# Using data attributes for jquery to relate two elements

Tags: jquery, variables, attr

One of the first things I learned in jQuery is the `Click()` function and how great it is at getting one element to effect another. However, what should I do when I have an array of items (all over my document) that I want to have effect a whole 'nother array of elements once again scatted across my document?

In my strange mind, I am thinking to use data attributes. You can see a VERY simplified version here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qnzpg/

First off, my example on jsfiddle has many a better solutions, I am aware. However, the real application is a bit more complex and requires this method.

I am trying to pass the value of my data attribute as a variable, and have the element that shares that variable be effected (in my example, by having it add a class):

```
$("#menu [data-cell]").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault;

    //make the data value a variable
    var $cell = $(this).data();

    //find the other element with the same data value and add the class named "open"
    $('#pages [data-cell='$cell']').addClass('open');
});
```

I've been fiddling with my jQuery for a very long time now and feel it's best to call in the experts.

What here am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('#menu li a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var attr = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-cell');
        $('#pages div').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            if($(this).attr('data-cell') == attr) {
                $(this).addClass('open');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qnzpg/7/

Comment: Any luck here? I'm interested to find out if this worked for you :)

Comment: Though this didn't work in my actual application, this helped me get what I did wrong. I would like to know why you decided to use `.each()` though. Can you explain why that makes things work?

Comment: Hi @invot, thanks for the feedback here. http://api.jquery.com/each/ is a looping construct that allows you to set context for each item, in this case each link, and then relate the code that follows to that context. You can read it like: for each link, when clicked, store the specified attribute as a variable... and then for each specified div, check for the same attribute variable, and perform some actions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have proper syntax for your string concatenation, and I think you want to grab only the value for the `data-cell` attribute.

```
var $cell = $(this).data('cell');
$('#pages [data-cell="' + $cell + '"]')
```

Though to be safe, I wrapped the selector value with double quotes in case the data has a space.

Answer (score 1):

I made modification to your code and now run correctly

Well first i think that you are wrong because you didn't concatenate the variable $cell but after i realized you dont get the attr data-cell, and you need get the value from data-cell something like this:

```
var $cell = $(this).attr('data-cell');
```

and need concatenate $cell like that

```
$('#pages [data-cell='+$cell+']').toggle('open');
```